# How to set attributes to the other items in array besides the selected element (this)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

I would like to make buttons in my HTML while one of my JS classes is running and receives a response from the backend. I'm using jQuery and vanilla JS and created an example below. In this example, I'd like to dynamically disable the button that was not clicked to show the user that something is happening and that they should not click elsewhere until a response is returned.

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("upload-button")).forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click",
        function(){
            let buttonSpinner = this.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
            buttonSpinner.classList.remove("d-none");
            // here I would like to disable the button that wasn't selected
            let destination = this.value;
            uploadData(destination, buttonSpinner);
        }
    )
})

function uploadData(destination, buttonSpinner){
    let link = "https://www.google.com/";
    let description = "Stack Overflow";
    new Upload(link, description, destination, buttonSpinner)
}

class Upload {
  constructor(link=null, description=null, destination="submit", buttonSpinner=null){
    this.link = link;
    this.description = description;
    this.destination = destination;
    this.buttonSpinner = buttonSpinner;
    this.log();
    this.disableButtonSpinner();
  }

  log(){
    console.log(this.link)
   }
  
  wait(){
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000)); // wait for data to return from backend
  }
  
   async disableButtonSpinner(){
    await this.wait() // simulate backend returning data
    this.buttonSpinner.classList.add("d-none");
   }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary upload-button" id="upload-user-data-button" value="data">
        Upload & View My Data
        <span class="ms-2 spinner-border spinner-border-sm d-none" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary upload-button" id="upload-submit-button" value="submit">
        Upload & Submit
        <span class="ms-2 spinner-border spinner-border-sm d-none" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like that, looping over all buttons to disable/re-enable them on click.

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("upload-button")).forEach((button, index) => {
    button.addEventListener("click",
        function(){
            let buttonSpinner = this.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
            buttonSpinner.classList.remove("d-none");
            // here I would like to disable the button that wasn't selected
            let buttons = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("upload-button"));
            buttons.forEach((button, i)=>{
              i!==index?button.disabled=true:null;
            })
            let destination = this.value;
            uploadData(destination, buttonSpinner);
        }
    )
})

function uploadData(destination, buttonSpinner){
    let link = "https://www.google.com/";
    let description = "Stack Overflow";
    new Upload(link, description, destination, buttonSpinner)
}

class Upload {
  constructor(link=null, description=null, destination="submit", buttonSpinner=null){
    this.link = link;
    this.description = description;
    this.destination = destination;
    this.buttonSpinner = buttonSpinner;
    this.log();
    this.disableButtonSpinner();
  }

  log(){
    console.log(this.link)
   }
  
  wait(){
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000)); // wait for data to return from backend
  }
  
   async disableButtonSpinner(){
    await this.wait() // simulate backend returning data
    this.buttonSpinner.classList.add("d-none");
    let buttons = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("upload-button"))
    buttons.forEach(button=>button.disabled=false)
   }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary upload-button" id="upload-user-data-button" value="data">
        Upload & View My Data
        <span class="ms-2 spinner-border spinner-border-sm d-none" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary upload-button" id="upload-submit-button" value="submit">
        Upload & Submit
        <span class="ms-2 spinner-border spinner-border-sm d-none" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: although this does work it's not ideal for a situation with more than 2 buttons - like you said a quick hack. i did learn something from your answer tho, thanks

Comment: @DanielJerrehian ok i upadated my code to make it work with more buttons as you wished

Comment: thanks a lot. i like how yours makes the buttons clickable afterwards too so i gave u the answer. appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You can add a parameter in the function to access the click event I used e. Then You can loop through your buttons and disable other than events target. This is achieved by `Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("upload-button")).forEach(insideButton => { if(e.target !== insideButton)  insideButton.disabled = true});`

```js
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("upload-button")).forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener("click",
            function(e){
                let buttonSpinner = this.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
                buttonSpinner.classList.remove("d-none");
                // here I would like to disable the button that wasn't selected        
                 Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("upload-button")).forEach(insideButton => {
                 if(e.target !== insideButton) 
                 insideButton.disabled = true});
                let destination = this.value;
                uploadData(destination, buttonSpinner);
            }
        )
    })

    function uploadData(destination, buttonSpinner){
        let link = "https://www.google.com/";
        let description = "Stack Overflow";
        new Upload(link, description, destination, buttonSpinner)
    }

    class Upload {
      constructor(link=null, description=null, destination="submit", buttonSpinner=null){
        this.link = link;
        this.description = description;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.buttonSpinner = buttonSpinner;
        this.log();
        this.disableButtonSpinner();
      }

      log(){
        console.log(this.link)
       }
      
      wait(){
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000)); // wait for data to return from backend
      }
      
       async disableButtonSpinner(){
        await this.wait() // simulate backend returning data
        this.buttonSpinner.classList.add("d-none");
       }
    }
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary upload-button" id="upload-user-data-button" value="data">
            Upload & View My Data
            <span class="ms-2 spinner-border spinner-border-sm d-none" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary upload-button" id="upload-submit-button" value="submit">
            Upload & Submit
            <span class="ms-2 spinner-border spinner-border-sm d-none" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: but one issue is its not re-enabling the button after the event is completed.

Comment: After the request is finished you can run the same loop and enable all the buttons. For example, you can add the loop in your disableButtonSpinner method after the first line. 
await this.wait() // simulate backend returning data
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("upload-button")).forEach(insideButton => {  insideButton.enabled= true});

Answer (score 0):

adding this solution to fix the issue with @Raven solution where the buttons remain disables even after the operation is done.

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("upload-button")).forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener("click",
            async function(e){
                let buttonSpinner = this.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
                buttonSpinner.classList.remove("d-none");
                // here I would like to disable the button that wasn't selected        
                 Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("upload-button")).forEach(insideButton => {
                    if(e.target !== insideButton) 
                    insideButton.disabled = true}
                 );
                let destination = this.value;
                await uploadData(destination, buttonSpinner);
            }
        )
    })

    async function uploadData(destination, buttonSpinner){
        let link = "https://www.google.com/";
        let description = "Stack Overflow";
        await new Upload(link, description, destination, buttonSpinner)
    }

    class Upload {
      constructor(link=null, description=null, destination="submit", buttonSpinner=null){
        this.link = link;
        this.description = description;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.buttonSpinner = buttonSpinner;
        this.log();
        this.disableButtonSpinner();
      }

      log(){
        console.log(this.link)
       }
      
      wait(){
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000)); // wait for data to return from backend
      }
      
       async disableButtonSpinner(){
        await this.wait().then(()=>{
            Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("upload-button")).forEach(insideButton => {    
                insideButton.disabled = false;
            }
             );
        }) // simulate backend returning data
        this.buttonSpinner.classList.add("d-none");
       }
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary upload-button" id="upload-user-data-button" value="data">
            Upload & View My Data
            <span class="ms-2 spinner-border spinner-border-sm d-none" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary upload-button" id="upload-submit-button" value="submit">
            Upload & Submit
            <span class="ms-2 spinner-border spinner-border-sm d-none" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
        </button>
    </div>
```